# Linux system,use "top" command, what is the meaning of 'I' in top command S column，S --status

Tags: linux, shell, terminal, raspberry-pi

i try to run `top`command ,on raspberry pi terminal.the`S`column has some values like `I`.what's the meaning of I?

- is it mean idle?
- i run `man top`,but didn't get.
- [running picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z33Fz.png)
- [`man top` information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aqliv.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

top version:
`procps-ng 3.3.15`

`man top`:

```
29. S  --  Process Status
   The status of the task which can be one of:
       D = uninterruptible sleep
       I = idle
       R = running
       S = sleeping
       T = stopped by job control signal
       t = stopped by debugger during trace
       Z = zombie
```